# Can Amazon Lex translate responses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, translation, amazon-lex

We're currently doing a bit of work around creating a multilingual chat-bot.  We've got English working as expected with our set responses.  However, upon adding a language, we can ask the bot a question in that language but the response is still in english.  Is there a way to automatically translate the response we've already created in English, or do we have to add them all manually?

Thanks